# Choice for each item in field in models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

## If i have 5 diffent sport in Sports then in Intrest model i want to put level to each of those 5 sports seprately,and want to print.How to do it.

exampl:cricket=Advance

Football=Beginner
like this

```
            class Sports(models.Model):
                Sport=models.CharField(max_length=30)

            class User(models.Model):
                user=models.CharField(max_length=30)

            class Intrest(models.Model):
                user_name=models.Foreignkey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                sport=models.Foreignkey(Sports,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
                LEVEL=(
                    ('1','Beginer'),
                    ('2','Intermediate'),
                    ('3','Advance'),
                    ('4','Nevel Played'),
                )
                Level=models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=LEVEL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy! You need to use your Foreignkey fields!

```
cricket = Sports.objects.get(Sport='cricket')
interest = Interest.objects.(sport=cricket)
cricket_level = interest.Level
print(cricket_level)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your `models.py` will end up looking. Other configs should be done in `admin.py` or `your_custom_form.py`.

Check out [Inline formsets](http://kevindias.com/writing/django-class-based-views-multiple-inline-formsets/)

```
class Sport(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class User(models.Model):
    user=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sport=models.ForeignKey('Interest', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Interest(models.Model):
    sport=models.Foreignkey(Sport,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Level_CHOICES=(
                    ('1','Beginner'),
                    ('2','Intermediate'),
                    ('3','Advanced'),
                    ('4','never played'),
                )
    level=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=Level_CHOICES)
```

Comment: i want if a user come then he has to put level for all intrested sports at once

Comment: according to your second option there will be many posts equal to no of sportsd

Comment: i want in only post user fill his all level as per sports

Comment: cricket='advance'
baseball='not played'
tennis='beninner'
pool='intermediate' like this at once

Comment: Okay. Are you using django administration to add your data? Or do you want to create custom forms?

Comment: none of above,i am simply creating an api,in which user will select level for each sports at once,